# Getting 400 Bad Request when passing a large String in Flask API request

Tags: python, flask, http-post

Might be a noob question, but I didn't find the solution anywhere else.

I have an API in Flask -

```
@app.route('/post-document-string', methods=['POST']) 
def parse_data():
    req_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    text = req_data['text']
    result = documentUtil.parse(text)
    return jsonify(keywords = result)
```

If I pass a String that is big enough, like 1000 words, it throws -
**400 Bad Request**

But if I pass a small String, like 200 words, it works fine.

**My questions are -**

1. Does flask have a limit to how much data I can pass in request from frontend ? If yes, how to change it ?
2. What is the best way in Flask API requests to pass a big String from front end ?

Comment: you should pass it directly as a file attachment. POST and GET both have limitations for how large the body content can be

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a limitation in **get_json** method.
Try this.

```
json_data = request.json
text = json_data['text']
```